# When multiple variables refer to same python list, and if value of one variable is changed, other variable is also changed autommatically. Why?

Tags: python, dynamic-binding

I have the below small code in Python where I am changing the value of `list_one` by using `pop()` function but I am not doing any changes in `list_two`. on printing `list_one` and `list_two` they both print the same results as mentioned below.

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
list_one = arr
list_two = arr
list_one.pop(0)

print(list_one)
print(list_two)

Output:
[2, 3, 4, 5]
[2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Can someone please help me understand why `list_two` is also changing even though I did not make any changes into it. I understand that both list_one and list_two refer to 'arr' but I was expecting `list_one` to create new reference to the modified list, and was expecting `list_two` to maintain existing reference to 'arr'.

please help me out.

Comment: Because, as you say, both variables refer to the same list.

Comment: A must read: [Facts and myths about Python names and values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that when you assign an array to `list_one` or `list_two`, you basically assigning the reference to the array, they are pointing to the same resource. So, since the two variables have the same reference to array, they do not only have equal values, but the values **are the same** as well.

You can also [copy an array](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/array-copying-in-python/) if needed, but assigning an array to a variable does not copy the whole array.

The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html) also state it, like this:

> Assignment statements in Python do not copy objects, they create bindings between a target and an object. For collections that are mutable or contain mutable items, a copy is sometimes needed so one can change one copy without changing the other. This module provides generic shallow and deep copy operations (explained below).